# Entering ':00 gives :002 in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here I have `':00` entered in the formula bar.

[image]

When I press enter I'm then given `':002` in the formula and `:002` in the cell.

[image]

I've tried setting cells to general, text, time. This doesn't make any sense why it would randomly throw a 2 on there for no reason whatsoever.

Comment: Better edit the post and include the Formula you have tried so far. will help us to fix the issue!!

Comment: because there is  a ':002 values in the same column. Excel just auto insert when you typed its header.. ( ':00 )

Comment: Rajesh, the image is the formula it is suppose to be the header. The first picture is what i have in the cell and the second picture is what I'm given when I press enter. Phidot, there are no other values in the column I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out, I had another column with "0" earlier in the worksheet and Excel needs to have the columns be uniquely named in order for that column to be referenced as a range. Didn't think this was initially the cause because the second column had the colon in front.